# simply scroll plugin displays white space before initiating the loop

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, simplyscroll

I am using simply scroll on the site http://smokehouseradio.com which I am developing. I have explicitly set the width to 100% to the horizontal scroller for responsiveness. However when implementing horizontal scroll in loop, I find that the scroller leaves a white space before starting the next loop. I do not want that. I want the images/loop to be continuous. How do I fix this?

Any help appreciated.

Plugin page : http://logicbox.net/jquery/simplyscroll/